# When to choose the intransitive « taper sur » over the transitive « taper », and vice versa

Tags: choix-de-mot

I said jokingly, commenting on someone’s temperamental nature:

> Mais, à vous entendre, c'est  une folle survoltée qui ne fait que **taper sur** tout le monde !

But what if I had dropped the preposition « sur », making it the transitive verb instead?

> vs : Mais, à vous entendre, c'est  une folle survoltée qui ne fait que **taper** tout le monde !

Comment: You should say "***c'est*** *une folle*" instead of "***elle est*** une folle*". Use "*elle est*" when followed by an adjective ("*elle est folle*") , or if "*est*" is an auxiliary "*est est tombée*". When it's follow by a noun or nominal groupe, use "*c'est*" : "*C'est ma mère*", "*c'est une personne que j'aime beaucoup*" etc. I have no clue about the part on "taper" though. Apart from the fact that when it's figurative, you should use "*taper* ***sur***", I can't find something like a rule.

Comment: Taper/ taper sur  & toucher/ toucher à should be 2 different questions.

Comment: @TeleportingGoat Precisely! What was I thinking?!

Comment: @Laure I was under the impression that practically the same rule would apply to both cases, but apparently not. I just split them into two separate posts. Merci.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quand il s'agit de donner des coups à quelqu'un on dit **taper sur (quelqu'un)**. Le [*Dictionnaire culturel en langue française*](http://www.lerobert.com/feuilletage/9782850363023/book.html), dit que l'emploi transitif de « taper » dans le sens de « taper sur quelqu'un » est du langage enfantin.

Si j'entends la phrase :

> c'est une folle survoltée qui ne fait que taper tout le monde

je ne suis pas sûre, et ce malgré le début de la phrase, de quel sens du verbe taper il s'agit.

Dans un sens familier, « taper » employé de façon transitive et  avec une personne en complément d'objet veut dire soit « emprunter / se faire donner de l'argent ».

Le *Dictionnaire culturel en langue française* donne cet exemple de taper employé de façon transitive (le sens est sans ambiguïté quand on lit le texte) :

> « Dépouillé par son mari, tapée par son frère, volée par son avouée, grugée par les domestiques, Margot s'est embastillée dans une sérénité funèbre » (Colette, *La vagabonde*)

Mais je ne dis pas qu'il soit interdit d'employer « taper » de façon transitive, surtout si le contexte est clair, par exemple une mère pourrait dire à un son enfant :

> Si t'arrêtes pas de taper ta sœur je te punis.

Il me semble que je perçois une différence entre « taper » et « taper sur ». En disant :

> Si t'arrêtes pas de taper sur ta sœur je te punis.

je pense que je fais plus ressortir la violence et la répétition des coups. *Taper* me semble  plus « léger » que *taper sur*.
En fait quand il s'agit de donner des coups sur quelqu'un on préfère « frapper » (voire « battre ») à « taper » ou « taper sur ».

À noter que « taper sur » au sens figuré veut dire : « dire du mal de quelqu'un ».

« Toucher » et « toucher à » devrait être une autre question. Il n'y a aucun rapport.

Comment: Pour taper dans le sens "*emprunter de l'argent*", on dit plutôt "*taper à*" non ? Ou *taper* tout court à la limite, mais je vois mal "*taper sur*" dans ce sens là. Il n'y a pas d'ambigüité là-dessus à mon avis. À part ça, je suis tout à fait d'accord avec le reste.

Comment: @TeleportingGoat Oops ai-je écrit que « taper sur  » voulait dire prendre de l'argent ?  je ne dois pas avoir les yeux en face des trous.... où ?  Mais je voulais bien dire taper quelqu'un (transitif), il m'a tapé vingt balles, je me suis fait taper vingt balles, j'ai tapé vingt balles à mon pote, etc.

Comment: Ah pardon, j'ai du mal comprendre ! Tu as parlé de ça juste après "*Je suis pas sûre de quel sens du verbe taper il s'agit*", j'ai compris que c'était une des interprétations de la phrase.

Comment: @TeleportingGoat  Ok donc question de ponctuation. J'enlève la majuscule.

Answer (score 2):

From what I read, basically "*taper*" means "to hit (once)", while "*taper sur*" means "to give a beating (hit repeatedly)*"

"*Taper*" has many meanings, but it's pretty rare said alone to mean "hit". (Like Laure said it's considered childish). Use "*taper sur*" instead.