# When to use the intransitive « toucher à » and when to use the transitive « toucher »

Tags: choix-de-mot

Expanding on a similar post about [« taper sur » vs « taper »](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/23987/when-to-choose-the-intransitive-taper-sur-over-the-transitive-taper-and), I have the same question here about how the intransitive « toucher à » compares with its transitive counterpart « toucher ».

> Ne **touchez** pas **à** quoi que ce soit dans ce labo. Ça pourrait se ressentir sur mes résultats.
>
> vs : Ne **touchez** pas quoi que ce soit dans ce labo. Ça pourrait se ressentir sur mes résultats.

Comment: Ne touchez pas aux choses, ne me touchez pas. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Moving my answer as well.*

I'd say "*toucher à*" is used when you're not supposed to touch.

If you can break something, change settings on a software, etc. It even work for flirting with someone you're not supposed to : "*Personne (ne) **touche à** ma copine, c'est compris ?*".

Answer (score 1):

Ne me touchez pas. Don't touch me. Transitive.
Ne touche pas la casserole. Elle est chaude. Transitive.

Ne touchez pas à ces papiers. Don't mess with these papers {touch, disturb, mess with, involve yourself with}

When it's the idea of mess with or involve yourself with: toucher à. Intransitive.

http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/toucher