# Pas touche à mes frites !

Tags: expressions, vocabulaire

In Paris I noticed an ad for some fast food or other that joked, « C'est à moi. Pas touche ! »

To a learner, this idiomatic expression naturally sounds like an inversion of the expected « [Ne] touche pas ». But how did it come to be this way?

For the etymology, Wiktionnaire simply links *pas* and *toucher* and adds « [siècle à préciser](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/pas_touche) ». Meanwhile, the TLF, as usual not the strongest on multi-word phrases, has no entry. My Robert Micro doesn't mention it and neither does Larousse. Google results show it alive and well, though.

1. Where did this expression come from and how did it function syntactically?

*Edit: This second part of my question turns out to be duplicated elsewhere.*

<strike>What's more, my searches for the expression turned up some odd behaviour: namely, that this expression tends to be followed by *à* as if *toucher* were not transitive, suggesting that there is not much of the original *toucher* left *qua* transitive verb. « [Pas touche à mes frites !](http://www.journaldemontreal.com/2011/09/16/pas-touche-a-mes-frites) »</strike>

2. Why is this expression followed by *à* instead of the direct object?

Merci !

Comment: This might help a bit: https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/23993/when-to-use-the-intransitive-toucher-%C3%A0-and-when-to-use-the-transitive-touc Great minds, eh? :)

Comment: Similar constructions are used when talking to dogs: "pas bouger!" (Except the verb is in infinitive form)

Comment: @QuentinRuyant Perhaps short for « Il ne faut pas bouger ! »

Comment: @LukeSawczak not sure, it's more like an order

Comment: @LukeSawczak Indeed, it is the imperative form preceded by *“pas”*, to order the opposite of the verb. Not a standard way of doing it, but in line with “Pas touche!” indeed. Perhaps a sentence starting with *“Pas”* gets toddlers attentive to what is being told to them in a simple manner that they will understand: *“Pas dans ta bouche!”, “Pas par là-bas!”, “Pas dans l’escalier!”, “Pas de l’eau partout!”*, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plus généralement le *DHLF/Rey* dit 1564 pour l'emploi du verbe *toucher* dans l'*intervention* consistant à dire de *ne pas toucher la nourriture* dans le sens de « ne pas manger ». Par ailleurs on trouve au lexique :

> − *P. ell., pop.* [Pour interdire de toucher à qqc.] *Pas touche! pas
>   touche, bébé!* (Dict. xx<sup>e</sup>s.).
>
> [ *TLFi*, [*toucher*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/toucher) II. A. 1. a) β) ]

Donc populaire, par ellipse (*ne... pas*), attesté au 20<sup>e</sup>. On trouve l'expression dans une chanson des années 1970 de Lisette Malidor... [*Pas touche !*](http://www.bide-et-musique.com/song/13176.html) Je pensais avoir entendu ça dans [*Dur dur d'être bébé*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dur_dur_d%27%C3%AAtre_b%C3%A9b%C3%A9_!) (Jordy) mais il dit (se faire dire) plutôt « touche pas ça » où seule la particule *ne* tombe...

Comment: J'ai aussi pensé à l'idée du [langage enfantin](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/Cat%C3%A9gorie:Langage_enfantin_en_fran%C3%A7ais) dans le contexte de l'[acquisition du langage](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acquisition_du_langage) mais je n'ai pas vraiment trouvé d'information en jetant un coup d’œil à ces documents. Merci !

Comment: C'est pure conjecture mais il est possible que cela vienne de "(toi) pas toucher" en "petit-nègre" qui aurait ensuite été "conjugué"...juste une idée comme ça.

Comment: L'expression est attestée en 1904 ( *Oh ! Pas touche, pas touche, mon cher ami* Le petit français illustré: journal des écoliers et des écolières, Volume 17, n° 1 ) et date donc certainement du XIX<sup>e</sup> siècle, voire plus tôt encore.

Comment: Le TLFi parle d'ellipse mais finalement entre _pas touche_ et _touche pas_ c'est l'ellipse de la même particule (ne) et c'est l'inversion qui fait plutôt la différence, et dont on n'a pas traité. On n'a pas précisé que c'était l'impératif ; ni quelle était la phrase entière et si c'était exactement _ne pas toucher_ ou _ne touche pas_. Enfin on remarque avec [l'exemple de jlliagre](https://archive.org/stream/pfi1905s1#page/n237/mode/2up/) que c'est dit deux fois de suite, comme dans l'exemple au TLFi... pourquoi donc ? Une meilleure réponse est certainement possible. Merci !

Comment: @onvousaouï Langage enfantin, ou peut-être adultes simplifiant volontairement leur langage pour s'adresser à de petits enfants, puis incorporant par la suite occasionnellement ce genre de tournure dans leurs relations entre adultes?

Comment: @Feelew Peut-être mais j'ai plutôt tendance à penser que l'expression a commencé à être utilisée entre adultes parlant argot. Je ne vois aucun autre exemple d'inversion de ce style avec l'impératif, c'est toujours l'infinitif que l'on observe autrement. Je vois mal des personnes parlant argot entre elles utiliser une expression enfantine comme le sont les inversion habituelles: *pas manger, pas toucher, pas dire, pas crier...*

Comment: @onvousaouï J'ai trouvé une référence au langage enfantin dans *Le bon usage* (§806 dans la 14e édition, sinon voir l'index à *Toucher)*. Je ne suis pas personnellement convaincu de la valeur de l'explication, mais la source du moins est très reconnue.

Comment: Quelque relation possible que ce soit avec *sainte nitouche (n'y touche)*?

Comment: @Feelew Merci, oui j'ai pensé à la _sainte_ mais je ne me souviens plus. Bonne trouvaille pour 806 ds. le contexte de l'infinitif présent même si ils n'élaborent pas vraiment. Je vais citer pour utilisation future au besoin : « Relevons aussi la phrase injonctive familière _Pas touche !_ réduction de _Ne pas toucher !_ (d'abord dans la langue des enfants) : _Elle refusa sa bouche au baiser et, comme il posait les mains sur ses hanches, se dégagea d'un geste onduleux assez joli. / - Pas TOUCHE ! dit-elle_ (DUTOURD, _Au Bon Beurre_, p. 71). [...] » (LBU14 §806) L'« allégorie » de Jordy...

Comment: ou le Jordy comme tel, un peu comme vous le disiez il y a qq. commentaires, et/ou l'argot... ou comment l'argot reprendrait ça etc. Les commentaires sont bien intéressants. Je ne sais pas vraiment comment expliquer ce qui n'est expliqué finalement nulle part... Merci !